# Only show react-native component if there's enough space (using rn flexbox)

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to know how to only show a component when there's enough space by using **flexbox** attributes available in **react-native**.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <Text>
        Text with unknown length
    </Text>
    <Text>
        Some more text with unknown length
    </Text>
    <Text>
        this should be hidden if the above text is too long
    </Text>
<View>
```

I won't know the width of the first 2 text components, so how can I make sure the last Text component only shows when there's enough space on the screen?

Thanks

> p.s: Don't be quick to mark my question as duplicate, as I'm asking
>   about react-native and not flexbox in general. The `auto` value is not
>   supported in **react-native flexbox**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that I should not be shown at all? Or only part of it? I assume the first.

One possible "workaround" is to set fix height and wrap content inside (overflow hidden).

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', height: 15, backgroundColor: 'yellow', overflow:'hidden' }}>
    <Text>
        Text with unknown length
    </Text>
    <Text>
        Some more text with!
    </Text>
    <Text>
        this should be hidden if the above text is too long
    </Text>
</View>
```

See working example on https://snack.expo.io/ryAmTJgVZ

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you I didn't know `overflow:'hidden'` works with `flexWrap`